# with impure pipe angular throw error "expression has been changed after it was checked"

Tags: angular, pipe

Angular 6.1.10

In my component, I want to change current timestamp with humanize form using moment js and develop this pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
    name: 'momentSuffix',
    pure: false
})
export class MomentSuffixPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): any {
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return moment(value)
                .startOf('seconds')
                .fromNow();
        }
    }
}
```

in HTML

```
 {{dateInTimeStamp | momentSuffix }}
```

But it gives below error when the time changed, not all the time

> expression has been changed after it was checked, previous: null, current: 33 minutes ago .

how to fix that?

Comment: I think you should leave your pipe pure and find other means to have it updated. The return value should only change when a parameter value changes. If you pass the time to the pipe, why did you make it impure?

Comment: Your pipe is indeed impure, since its output depends on something other than its arguments (i.e. the current time). But since the current time moves by itself during the change detection, it violates angular rules. So either you cheat and mark it pure (but then the output won't refresh itself as the time moves), or you use a component, which for example recomputes its displayed value every minute.

Comment: I have tried with `pure: true` but this does not change the value over time. I want to change time automatically as soon as time pass. so that *a seconds ago* would change to *1 minute ago* after passing the time without refreshing the page. i e. recompute

Comment: Then use a component that recomputes the value it displays every minute or so.

Comment: but this is also a bad practice. to call a method on HTML because this list comes dynamically and one of item in list has the timestamp. I can not recreate the list on component.ts file

Comment: Using components in angular is bad practice? How so? I have no idea of what you mean by "call a method on HTML". I never advised you to do any of that. Only to design a component able to display a timestamp the way you want to, and which refreshes the value it displays every minute or so.